# Why subdomain not working after rename in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, apache2

I had xyz.mydomain.com subdomain in ubuntu server.It was working fine.

I just want to change that xyz to xyz1 , so i rename all folders as well as the virtual host settings in cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/

I used below commands...

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
sudo nano xyz1.mydomain.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xyz1.mydomain.com
ServerAlias www.xyz1.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/xyz1/
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/xyz1/>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
sudo a2ensite xyz1.mydomain.com
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
sudo a2enmod vhost_alias
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Now i am unable to view xyz1.mydomain.com website. Is there any thing missing?

Answer (score 0):

If your output posted is correct, you ended the `<VirtualHost>` statement before the `<Directory>` statement. Move the `</VirtualHost>` line to the end and reload your config.

Comment: I moved the </VirtualHost> line to the end. But still not working. It actually linking to "/etc/apache2/sites-available/ default" ...

Comment: Not sure.. Did you check the permissions/owner/group of the directories and files after you renamed them?

Comment: There is no issues in permission also.. is there any other place need to configure?

Comment: Out of ideas, sorry.